# What's the current of an aromatic ring?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy, aromaticity, magnetism

Aromatic molecules like benzene have a [ring current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_ring_current), created by the movement of electrons around the ring. This is most visible during proton NMR, when the magnetic field of the ring current opposes that of the NMR superconductor.

What's the current though?  How fast are electrons moving around the ring at room temperature?

Comment: Well, they don't exactly "have" it.  Ring current can be induced in the ring by magnetic field, like in any loop of conductor. Afaik actual velocities of drift of electrons in electric currents are very small, negligible in comparison with overall speed of electrons.